# How to get all attributes of a object mapped inside another with Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have the code below in Grails:

```
class Person{
    String name

    Address address

}

class Address{

    String addressDescription

}

Address addressX = new Address(addressDescription:"Avenue xxx");

address.save(); 

Person p = new Person(name:"MyName",address:addressX);

p.save();
```

So, after the objects have been saved, I tried to get person like this:

`Person p = Person.findByName("MyName");`

but, when a try get `p.getAddress()` I get only the Address ID, is that correct? 
Is there a way to bring all the properties automatically with the object person ?

I know that a can do `Address.findById(p.address.id)` but I don't want make more queries.

Thanks for help!

Comment: By default, address will be lazy loaded. How do you know you're only getting the ID? The debugger may show this, but if you access `p.address.shortDescription`, what happens? (Note you don't have to use the `getter`, groovy takes care of that for you.

Comment: Exactly I was seeing by debug, you right, when a try acess without "get" it's works, thanks so much.

Comment: "but, when a try get p.getAddress() I get only the Address ID, is that correct?" - No, that isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections are generally lazy loaded by default. When you look at the data through a debugger, you will generally not see any of the lazy loaded properties. However, once you access them, they will be there:

`p.address.shortDescription`